# How to get the names of all products?

Tags: javascript

I want to get only the names of objects (cat, dog, bird)

```js
/// objects from which I want to get a name ///
   

 var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfield", count: 3443, price: 1000}},
    {bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}},
    {dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}}
    ];

    function  getAllProductNames(storage) {
        var keys = [];
        for(var key in storage) {
            keys.push(key);
            if(typeof storage[key] === "object") {
                var subkeys = getAllProductNames(storage[key]);
                keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                    return key + "." + subkey;
                }));
            }
        }
        console.log(keys);
        return keys;
    }
    getAllProductNames(storage);
```

Comment: post what you expect as output?

Comment: i need names: "Garfield", "Eagle", "Rex" rather than object names

Comment: see my edit here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088954/3723368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the first key of the objects by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating the array and returning the property with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
function  getAllProductNames(storage) {
    return storage.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].name);
}

var storage = [{ cat: { name: "Garfield", count: 3443, price: 1000 } }, { bird: { name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000 } }, { dog: { name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000 } }  ];

console.log(getAllProductNames(storage));
```

Comment: i need name: "Garfield", "Eagle", "Rex" rather than object names

Answer (score 2):

```js
var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfield", count: 3443, price: 1000}},
    {bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}},
    {dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}}
    ];
var names = []; 
storage.map(function(a){
  names.push(Object.keys(a)[0]);
})
console.log(names );
```

Answer (score 2):

With simple [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```js
var index = 0;
var keys = []
var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfield", count: 3443, price: 1000}},
    {bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}},
    {dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}}
    ];

for(index in storage) {
      keys.push(Object.values(storage[index])[0].name)
}
console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your each storage object has multiple products

```
var allProduct = [];
storage.forEach((obj) => {allProduct.push(...Object.keys(obj))})
console.log(allProduct)
```